# Sending Raw Binary Data Between Two Servers With Websockets/Node.js?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I've been reading lately about Node.js, Websockets and Socket.io out of curiosity.  However, the other day I was thinking of a problem one of my client faces and was wondering if they may be the solution.   Essentially, there are two servers.  Server 1, is serving raw binary data.  Server 2, is setup to receive and handle that binary data.

What needs to happen is data from server 1, is passed through a web browser and then delivered to server 2.

[image]

I'm curious to know if this is possible, and what angles you may take to solve it?

Comment: It is possible definitely, but why? What's the problem with the direct connections?
And I believe this is would be a slow data transition. And there are cases that socket.io won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible. The connections to both will need to be initiated from the browser/Javascript, but once in place it should be easy to proxy the data from one to the other.

However, there are many non-browser WebSocket clients so you might consider just making a direct WebSocket connection from one server to the other. See [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WebSocket_implementations) for WebSocket client (and server) implementations.